# On declaring variables as global gives different answers

Tags: c++, variables, global-variables, fibonacci

I have two similar codes

Code1:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

long long int MOD = 1000000007;

long long int fib(long long int n)
{
    if(n <= 2)
        return 1;
    long long int k = n/2;
    long long int a = fib(k+1);
    long long int b = fib(k);
    if(n%2 == 1)
        return (a*a + b*b)%MOD;
    else
    {
        long long c = 2*a - b;
        if(c < 0)
            c+=MOD;
        return (b*(c))%MOD;
    }
}

int main()
{
    long long int n;
    scanf("%lld",&n);
    printf("%lld\n", fib(n));
    return 0;
}
```

Here I define variables `k,a,b` as local variables. For `n = 100000000`, output is `908460138`.

Code2:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

long long int MOD = 1000000007;

long long int a,b,c,d,k;

long long int fib(long long int n)
{
    if(n <= 2)
        return 1;
    k = n/2;
    a = fib(k+1);
    b = fib(k);
    if(n%2 == 1)
        return (a*a + b*b)%MOD;
    else
    {
        c = 2*a - b;
        if(c < 0)
            c+=MOD;
        return (b*(c))%MOD;
    }
}

int main()
{
    long long int n;
    scanf("%lld",&n);
    printf("%lld\n", fib(n));
    return 0;
}
```

Here I define variables `k,a,b` as global variables. For `n = 100000000`, output is `265038576`.

Can anyone explain why do I get this difference in output. Code1 is giving correct output(but has a greater run time). How to resolve this?

Comment: Build a debug version, and step through the code in a debugger line by line to see what's the difference might be.

Comment: You should focus on code 2, which is the one that doesn't work, and debug it step by step.

Comment: Recursion and shared mutable state is an unpleasant combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using local variables, you have 'several' local variables `a,b,c,d,k` (one independent by scope).

When using global variables, you share the variable with the different call to `fib`:

so

```
a = fib(k+1);
b = fib(k);
```

The second call will modify previous `k`, `a` (if k > 2) and so have side effect for the current call.

Comment: k alone is shared right? But declaring k as local variable doesn't help either.

Comment: All your global variables are shared, `k` and `a` are really problematic, `b` and `c` usages are sufficient local to not exhibit problem currently. Still prefer local variables.